# Dash or Endash for "from ... to ..."?

Tags: typography

I'm trying to typeset "I have 2 to 4 apples."

Should I do:

```
I have 2-4 apples.
```

or

```
I have 2--4 apples.
```

?

Just using `2 to 4` will not work for my case.

Comment: in german typography you would use 2--4. But it can be different in other cultures.

Comment: In french typography too. Note that you can directly  type the endash: `2–4`

Comment: I think in Danish we use `3-5` but I usually tell users to use `3--5` as it looks better. Most Danish publishers don't care as long as you're consistent

Comment: I think, to the extent that `3-5` is accepted anywhere it's a result of bad typography becoming normalized. A hyphen in a range is no more acceptable than a leading apostrophe being replaced by ‘ which is all too common thanks to “smart” quote algorithms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Knuth's *The TeXbook*, one should do

```
I have 2--4 apples.
```

> (Page 4) ... En-dashes are used for number ranges like 'pages 13--34', and also in contexts like 'exercise 1.2.6--52'. ...

[image]